# Dataframe access second level of MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to figure out the best way to deal with a multiIndex. Especially when I want to access some values on the second level of the multiIndex.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(3,size=20),np.random.rand(20)]).T
df.columns = ['A','B']
g = df.groupby('A').describe()
```

Let's say I'm trying to look at the mean values of this output. I can do something like this:

```
idx = [True if a[1]=='mean' else False for a in g.index.tolist()]
p.loc[idx,:]
```

It works but there must be a better way to do this. Is there a better way to access the second level multiIndex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a couple of easy answers:

```
g.xs('mean', level=1)
```

Another one:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
g.loc[idx[:,'mean'],:]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should read over the documentation on multi-index data frames. IndexSlice is the way to handle this. Something like this should work.

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.IndexSlice
g.loc[idx[:,"mean"],:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the order of indexes in the multiindex:

```
g.reorder_levels([1,0]).loc['mean']
#            B
#A            
#0.0  0.515745
#1.0  0.451534
#2.0  0.483014
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this

```
g.loc[:, ("B", "mean")]

  A
0.0    0.381882
1.0    0.450356
2.0    0.497692
Name: (B, mean), dtype: float64
```

Check out [advanced indexing with hierarchical index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)